# Remove appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making a related multi-level selectes.

When the value of select changes there will be another select. Before it's created I want to remove all the previous selects after it. But it doesn't work. I have tried something like `.siblings()` or `.next()` to do experiment they don't work either. What's the problem or is there any better way to implement my idea?

```js
$('li').on("change", "select", function () {
  $(this).nextAll().remove(); //remove all the previous selects after which is changed.
  $(this).parents('li').append('<select data-mini="true"><option value="111">aaaa</option><option value="222">bbbb</option></select>').trigger('create');
});
```

Something like this.

```html
<select>
  <option>Europe</option>
  <option>Asia</option>
</select>

<!-- appended select -->

<select>
  <option>France</option>   
  <option>Germany</option>
</select>
```

When I change Europe to Asia, the appended select disappear and the below *selectmenu* is appended.

```html
<select>
  <option>China</option>
  <option>Japan</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to post some markup. Are these selects added with the same function, in which case they would be nested etc ?

Comment: all _select menu_ are in the same level? for _selectmenu_ use `.selectmenu` to enhance it, not `.trigger('create')`.

Comment: I can't post image so I added some html to express what I mean.

Comment: selectmenus share the same parent or each have a different one? in other words, all selectmenus are on the same level under one parent or no?

Comment: They have the same parent("<li>") in html.

Comment: This is weird, it's not working as you've stated. but I've made a work around http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s6tqJ/

Comment: I also have to try another way to do this, like the way you do I remove them by class.

Comment: Good luck and let us know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('li').on("change","select",function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').find('select').remove();  
    $(this).closest('li').append('<select data-mini="true"><option value="111">aaaa</option><option value="222">bbbb</option></select>')
    .trigger('create');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the parent because before removing this and siblings

```
$('li').on("change", "select", function () {
    var parLi = $(this).closest('li'); //saving parent
    $(this).siblings().remove().end().remove();
    parLi.append('<select data-mini="true"><option value="111">aaaa</option><option value="222">bbbb</option></select>').trigger('create');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYfLc/1/)